# Unity3D - Change local scale to world scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´m having some troubles when trying to instantiate prefabs on Unity. My main problem comes when trying to set the scale of the prefab, which has his own scale and make it the same as another GameObject´s scale which is already on the world to make both the same size. Since their local scale is not the same,even I set ,for example, both Y´s component to 1, they dont have the same height. How can I solve this through the script code

Comment: Were your assets/prefabs designed to be be the same size when they have the same scale? For example if you have a model of a building and a model of a car, they would normally be modeled such that when both have the same scale in the engine they would be proportionally sized (building bigger than car). If they were modeled to be different sizes then you will need to set the scale factor on the import inspector under "model" (it is the top most option) or you would need to figure out the scale required to make them even and apply that to the new prefab instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import the models from your modeling software, you need to adjust the `Scale Factor` so the models match in size. This way you will get them to match in size when they match in scale.

If you want to calculate the actual size from code. you can do it by using `Mesh.bounds`. An example:

```
Bounds bounds = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.bounds;
Vector3 size = bounds.size;
```

When you get the size, you can multiply the `localScale` to match the size of the other model.

You can find more information in documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html).